# BYTE to python C-Type structure Conversion Issue

Tags: python, python-2.7, structure, ctypes

I am facing a little problem on deserializing some bytes that have been received from the POSIX Queue.

We are trying to develop a module where a Python application will post a POSIX queue data to a C application and C will re-post data to Python Queue..

All data is Ctype Structure based.

Structure defintion:

**msgStruct.py**

```
MAX_MSG_SIZE = 5120
class MsgStruct(ctypes.Structure):
    _fields_ = [
                ("msgType", ctypes.c_int),
                ("msgSize",ctypes.c_int),
                ("setState",ctypes.c_int),
                ("msgBuf",ctypes.c_char * MAX_MSG_SIZE)
            ]
```

**conversions.py**

```
class conversions():
    def serialize(ctypesObj):
        """
        FAQ: How do I copy bytes to Python from a ctypes.Structure?
        """
        return buffer(ctypesObj)[:]

    def deserialize(ctypesObj, inputBytes):
        """
        FAQ: How do I copy bytes to a ctypes.Structure from Python?
        """
        fit = min(len(inputBytes), ctypes.sizeof(ctypesObj))
        ctypes.memmove(ctypes.addressof(ctypesObj), inputBytes, fit)
        return ctypesObj
```

**test.py**

```
from mapStruct import *
from conversions import conversions
wrapper=conversions()
data="\x01\x00\x00\x00\x70\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x02\x00\x00\x00\x1e\x00\x00\x00\x25\x42\x35\x32\x33\x39\x35\x31\x32\x35\x32\x34\x38\x39\x35\x30\x30\x36\x5e\x56\x45\x4e\x4b\x41\x54\x20\x52\x41\x47\x41\x56\x41\x4e\x20\x20\x20\x20\x20\x20\x20\x20\x20\x20\x20\x20\x5e\x31\x36\x30\x34\x31\x30\x31\x31\x36\x35\x35\x36\x30\x30\x31\x34\x31\x30\x30\x30\x30\x30\x30\x3f\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x3b\x35\x32\x33\x39\x35\x31\x32\x35\x32\x34\x38\x39\x35\x30\x30\x36\x3d\x31\x36\x30\x34\x31\x30\x31\x31\x34\x31\x30\x3f\x00\x00...\x00"
"""
Data is the Queue data that is recieved by python
"""
baseStruct=MsgStruct()
rxData=wrapper.deserialize(baseStruct,data)
print rxData.setState # Prints as expected
print rxData.msgType # Prints as expected
print rxData.msgSize
print rxData.msgBuf.encode('hex') # here is probles i dont C any data in this buffer
```

Please guide me on solving this issue. I am very much surprised that the buffer(rxData.msgSize) is always empty and would like to know why.

Comment: `deserialize()` returns `None` because you didn't explicitly `return` something else.

Comment: @martineau : oops while copying the code here i missed that..sorry .it actually returns ctypesObj.

Comment: The `msgSize` field is a `ctypes.c_int`, so what exactly do you expect `msgSize.encode('hex')` to do?

Comment: @martineau : sorry again a typo...corrected it..instead of msgBuf.encode('hex') substituted msgSize.encode('hex')..my msgBUf holds another structure data actually

Comment: The arguments are reversed on the `wrapper.deserialize(data,baseStruct)` call.

Comment: @martineau  : sorry again theses changes occured when i made this code to bits n pieces for this forum to get the solution why the msgBuf is always empty...but in orginal code in PC has arguments rightly placed..sorry for the inconvenience..

Comment: You need to define `conversions.serialize()` and `conversions.deserialize()` using `@staticmethod` so they don't receive the implicit first argument usually called `self` like regular methods.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ctypes` is trying to be helpful with `c_char` buffers by converting it into a Python string.  The conversion stops at the first null byte.  Observe what happens when I change the first couple bytes of data in your data buffer:

```
0
1
368
b'\x01\x02'
```

Change the type of `msgBuf` to `c_ubyte` instead so `ctypes` won't try to be "helpful" and then look at the data character-by-character with:

```
>>> print repr(''.join(chr(x) for x in rxData.msgBuf))
'\x00\x00\x00\x00\x02\x00\x00\x00\x1e\x00\x00\x00%B5239512524 ...
```

But there is no reason to use `ctypes` at all:

```
import struct

data=b"\x01\x00\x00\x00\x70\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01\x02\x00\x00\x02\x00\x00\x00\x1e\x00\x00\x00\x25\x42\x35\x32\x33\x39\x35\x31\x32\x35\x32\x34\x38\x39\x35\x30\x30\x36\x5e\x56\x45\x4e\x4b\x41\x54\x20\x52\x41\x47\x41\x56\x41\x4e\x20\x20\x20\x20\x20\x20\x20\x20\x20\x20\x20\x20\x5e\x31\x36\x30\x34\x31\x30\x31\x31\x36\x35\x35\x36\x30\x30\x31\x34\x31\x30\x30\x30\x30\x30\x30\x3f\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x3b\x35\x32\x33\x39\x35\x31\x32\x35\x32\x34\x38\x39\x35\x30\x30\x36\x3d\x31\x36\x30\x34\x31\x30\x31\x31\x34\x31\x30\x3f\x00\x00...\x00"

msg_offset = struct.calcsize('iii')
print struct.unpack_from('iii',data)
print repr(data[msg_offset:])
```

Output:

```
(1, 368, 0)
'\x01\x02\x00\x00\x02\x00\x00\x00\x1e\x00\x00\x00%B5239512524895006^VENKAT RAGAVAN            ^16041011655600141000000?\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00;5239512524895006=16041011410?\x00\x00...\x00'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`struct`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/struct.html) to unpack the data for you:

```
import struct
import ctypes

class MsgStruct(ctypes.Structure):
    _fields_ = [
                ("msgType", ctypes.c_int),
                ("msgSize",ctypes.c_int),
                ("setState",ctypes.c_int),
                ("msgBuf",ctypes.c_char * 5120)
            ]

def deserialize(data):
    sz = len(data)-struct.calcsize('iii')
    return MsgStruct(*struct.unpack('iii{}s'.format(sz), data))
```

Testing it with your data:

```
In [18]: data
Out[18]: '\x01\x00\x00\x00p\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x02\x00\x00\x00\x1e\x00\x00\x00%B5239512524895006^VENKAT RAGAVAN            ^16041011655600141000000?\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00;5239512524895006=16041011410?\x00\x00...\x00'

In [19]: s = deserialize(data)

In [20]: s.
s.msgBuf    s.msgSize   s.msgType   s.setState  

In [20]: s.msgType
Out[20]: 1

In [21]: s.msgSize
Out[21]: 368

In [22]: s.setState
Out[22]: 0
```

*Edit:* The `MsgStruct` assignment doesn't work for the `msgBuf` field. See the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5082753/how-do-i-build-a-python-string-from-a-ctype-struct) for the reason. Unpacking the struct works fine:

```
In [13]: sz=12

In [14]: struct.unpack('iii{}s'.format(len(data)-sz), data)
Out[14]: (1, 368, 0, '\x00\x00\x00\x00\x02\x00\x00\x00\x1e\x00\x00\x00%B5239512524895006^VENKAT RAGAVAN            ^16041011655600141000000?\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00;5239512524895006=16041011410?\x00\x00...\x00')
```

Comment: still confused why memove is not doing the needful.

Comment: You'd have to look into the implemantation of ctypes to answer that, I'm afraid.